# Apache Storm Maven dependency for KafkaProducerTopology object

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

What is the Maven dependency for importing `org.apache.storm.kafka.bolt.KafkaProducerTopology`  I used :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
        <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`
```

but it is not working. I need a Kafka-Server xml with valid version but I did not found in anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a class from the examples, not part of any Maven dependency

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-kafka-client-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/bolt/KafkaProducerTopology.java